# How to assign certain scores from a list to values in multiple lists and get the sum for each value in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, cumulative-sum

Could you explain how to assign certain scores from a list to values in multiple lists and get the total score for each value?

`score = [1,2,3,4,5]` assigne a score based on the position in the list

`l_1 = [a,b,c,d,e]`
assign a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5

`l_2 = [c,a,d,e,b]`
assign c=1, a=2, d=3, e=4, b=5

I am trying to get the result like
`{'e':9, 'b': 7, 'd':7, 'c': 4, 'a': 3}`

Thank you!

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `zip` the values of `score` to each list, which gives you a tuple of `(key, value)` for each letter-score combination.  Make each zipped object a `dict`.  Then use a dict comprehension to add the values for each key together.

```
d_1 = dict(zip(l_1, score))
d_2 = dict(zip(l_2, score))

{k: v + d_2[k] for k, v in d_1.items()}
# {'a': 3, 'b': 7, 'c': 4, 'd': 7, 'e': 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use `zip` function:

```
dic = {'a':0, 'b': 0, 'c':0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0}
def score(dic, *args):
    for lst in args:
        for k, v in zip(lst, range(len(lst))):
            dic[k] += v+1
    return dic

l_1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
l_2 = ['c','a','d','e','b']

score(dic, l_1, l_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

score = [1,2,3,4,5] # note: 0 no need to use this list if there is no scenario like [5,6,9,10,4]
l_1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
l_2 = ['c','a','d','e','b']

score_dict = defaultdict(int)

'''
for note: 0

if your score is always consecutive
like score = [2,3,4,5,6] or [5,6,7,8,9]...
you don't need to have seperate list of score you can set
start = score_of_char_at_first_position_ie_at_zero-th_index

like start = 2, or start = 5

else use this function

def add2ScoreDict( lst):
    for pos_score, char in zip(score,lst):
        score_dict[char] += pos_score

'''

def add2ScoreDict( lst):
    for pos, char in enumerate( lst,start =1):
        score_dict[char] += pos


# note: 1
add2ScoreDict( l_1)
add2ScoreDict( l_2)

#print(score_dict) # defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 3, 'b': 7, 'c': 4, 'd': 7, 'e': 9})

score_dict = dict(sorted(score_dict.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda x: x[1]))

print(score_dict) # {'e': 9, 'b': 7, 'd': 7, 'c': 4, 'a': 3}
```

edit 1:

if you have multiple lists put them in `list_of_list = [l_1, l_2]` so that you don't have to call func add2ScoreDict yourself again and again.

```
# for note: 1
for lst in list_of_list:
    add2ScoreDict( lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your lists in separate variables, you should put them in a list of lists so that you can iterate through it and calculate the sums of the scores according to each key's indices in the sub-lists:

```
score = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lists = [
    ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    ['c','a','d','e','b']
]
d = {}
for l in lists:
    for i, k in enumerate(l):
        d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + score[i]
```

`d` would become:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 7, 'c': 4, 'd': 7, 'e': 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use a `Counter` from the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html).

```
from collections import Counter

tally = Counter()
scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def add_scores(letters):
    for letter, score in zip(letters, scores):
        tally[letter] += score


L1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
add_scores(L1)
L2 = ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b']
add_scores(L2)

print(tally)
>>> python tally.py
Counter({'e': 9, 'b': 7, 'd': 7, 'c': 4, 'a': 3})
```

`zip` is used to pair letters and scores, a `for` loop to iterate over them and a `Counter` to collect the results. A `Counter` is actually a dictionary, so you can write things like

```
tally['a']
```

to get the score for letter `a` or

```
for letter, score in tally.items():
    print('Letter %s scored %s' % (letter, score))
```

to print the results, just as you would with a normal dictionary.

Finally, small ells and letter O's can be troublesome as variable names because they are hard to distinguish from ones and zeros. The Python style guide (often referred to as PEP8) [recommends avoiding them](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#names-to-avoid).

Answer (score 0):

You could `zip` both *lists* with `score` as one *list* `l3` then you could use *dictionary comprehension* with `filter`to construct your *dicitonary*. The `key` being index `1` of the the newly formed *tuples* in l3, and the value being the sum of all index `0`'s in l3 after creating a sublist that is filtered for only matching index `0`'s

```
score = [1,2,3,4,5] 

l_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 
l_2 = ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b'] 
l3 = [*zip(score, l_1), *zip(score,l_2)]

d = {i[1]: sum([j[0] for j in list(filter(lambda x: x[1] ==i[1], l3))]) for i in l3}
```

> ```
> {'a': 3, 'b': 7, 'c': 4, 'd': 7, 'e': 9}
> ```

Expanded Explanation:

```
d = {}
for i in l3:
    f = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == i[1], l3))
    vals = []
    for j in f:
        vals.append(j[0])
    total_vals = sum(vals)
    d[i[1]] = total_vals
```